# Even spacing between Excel legend entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When entries in an Excel legend have different lengths (and the font size is such that they take up different numbers of lines), the spacing between the text of each legend entry is uneven:

[image: Spacing between legend entries is currently uneven]

I realise that Excel gives each legend entry the same amount of space (i.e. spacing the coloured squares evenly), but when each entry has a different amount of text, this looks a bit silly (see picture above). It would look more natural for the spacing between the bottom line of text of one entry and the top of the next to be equal for all entries (as in the picture below).

[image: The desired even spacing between entries]

I have tried selecting, then dragging each legend entry individually, but it only seems to be possible to position the legend as a whole.

The only solution I can currently think of is exporting the image to an image editing program, then manually separating the legend entries and adjusting spacing.

Is there a way to adjust this spacing from within Excel itself? Or are there any other options for  automatically spacing text evenly?

[image: An example chart]

Comment: I fear that the only solution is to make all entries single-line. The legend area can be modified in height and width for that.

Comment: I haven't worked with this for far too long, but my first instinct would be to set the text to vertically align - middle. This will keep the dots in the center, but space out the text centered too.